# Join 2 table with different where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 table in my database

1.**admin_store_exam**
  Columns are
  *exam_name*, *A_QNum*, *math_ques, math_a, math_b, math_c, math_d, A_Ans*

2.**student_ans_history**
  Columns are
  *exam_name*, *S_ID*, *S_QNum*, *S_Ans*, *S_Noans*

Now I want to join these 2 tables on **exam_name** column with different WHERE Clause.

Here are the two different query with WHERE Clause.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM admin_store_exam WHERE exam_name='$en'";

$sql="SELECT * FROM student_ans_history WHERE exam_name='$en' AND S_ID='$session_contact'";
```

After join these 2 tables I got these.

```
$sql="
SELECT admin_store_exam.A_QNum
     , admin_store_exam.math_ques
     , admin_store_exam.math_a
     , admin_store_exam.math_b
     , admin_store_exam.math_c
     , admin_store_exam.math_d
     , admin_store_exam.A_Ans
     , student_ans_history.S_Ans
     , student_ans_history.S_Noans 
  FROM admin_store_exam 
 WHERE admin_store_exam.exam_name = '$en' 
  JOIN student_ans_history 
 WHERE student_ans_history.exam_name = '$en' 
   AND S_ID = '$session_contact' 
    ON admin_store_exam.exam_name = student_ans_history.exam_name
 ";
```

But unfortunately I won't get any result.
I am not very familiar with sql, so could not understand where I have done the mistake. Can anyone help me to get out this problem. Thanks..

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result to your question.

Comment: Your query has syntax errors please refer to official docs for correct syntax using joins

Comment: Well, a syntax error is a result of sorts. - See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join it like:

```
$sql="SELECT admin_store_exam.A_QNum
 , admin_store_exam.math_ques
 , admin_store_exam.math_a
 , admin_store_exam.math_b
 , admin_store_exam.math_c
 , admin_store_exam.math_d
 , admin_store_exam.A_Ans
 , CONCAT(S_Ans,S_Noans) AS S_Ans
  FROM admin_store_exam 
 INNER 
  JOIN student_ans_history 
    ON admin_store_exam.exam_name = student_ans_history.exam_name 
        AND admin_store_exam.A_QNum = student_ans_history.S_QNum
 WHERE admin_store_exam.exam_name = '$en' 
   AND student_ans_history.S_ID = '$session_contact'
    GROUP BY admin_store_exam.exam_name, admin_store_exam.A_QNum";
```

Hope this works!!!

Answer (score -2):

You can use sub-queries. Consider the following example:

```
SELECT A.* FROM
(SELECT * FROM admin_store_exam WHERE exam_name='AB') AS A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM student_ans_history WHERE exam_name='AB' AND S_ID='23344') AS B
ON A.exam_name = B.exam_name
```